# How to schedule a task to run Weekly but only on LogOn?

Tags: windows-7, scheduled-tasks

I have Windows 7 Ultimate 32 Bit. I wish to schedule a task to run weekly but at LogOn. e.g. Every Monday anytime I login to Windows the task should run.

I have gone thru the options but I believe I could not find any relevant option for such a requirement. You can either run a task at every logon or weekly.

Is there anyway to achieve this?

As a last resort, I will have to modify my program to run every logon but do the intended task every week.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can setup a trigger on the scheduled task to run `At log on` and to run as a `Specific User` so yes this means you will trigger the task to ***run at every logon*** for that ***specific user***.

You can add conditional logic to check for a few conditions, and based on these conditions and the logic, you can ensure it'll only run if ***the day is Monday*** or optionally you could have it run ***only once if the day is Monday***—checking that it wasn't already run for a specific `<YYYYMMDD>` date.

---

### Run for specific user at every login on Monday's only

> **Essentially this will:**
>
> 1. Stop running if the day ***is not Monday*** *(you don't want it to run on other days)*

### The Script

**Note:** After the `IF NOT [%DAY%]==[Mon] EXIT` logic, you can put additional batch logic, or even [Start](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html) or [Call](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html) an external process such as an executable file, etc.

```
@ECHO ON

SET DAY=%DATE:~0,3%
IF NOT [%DAY%]==[Mon] EXIT

<The rest of your batch logic below >
<Or you can CALL or START EXEs      >
<Scooby wanna scoobie snack         >
EXIT
```

---

### Bonus: Run only Once when it's Monday for Specific User

> **Essentially this will (in the specific order):**
>
> 1. Stop running if the day ***is not Monday*** *(you don't want it to run on other days)*
> 2. Stop running if the day ***is Monday*** and if a ***lock file exists*** *(see #3)*
>
>    - both conditions in #2 must be true
> 3. Create a `<YYYYMMDD>` named lock file if the ***day is Monday*** and the ***file doesn't exist*** already
> 4. If it makes it to #3 and creates the lock file, that will be the first run at the first login for that user account for that day. This means
>      subsequent logins for that same day *(i.e. `<YYYYMMDD>`)*, these same conditions should
>      never be met to allow the process to get to #3 again since if the lock file already
>      exists it stops running.

---

### The Script

**Note:** After the bottom most `IF [%DAY%]==[Mon] IF NOT EXIST "%userprofile%\~`logic, you can put additional batch logic, or even [Start](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html) or [Call](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html) an external process such as an executable file, etc.

```
@ECHO ON

SET DAY=%DATE:~0,3%
SET YYYYMMDD=%DATE:~10%%DATE:~4,2%%DATE:~7,2%
IF NOT [%DAY%]==[Mon] EXIT
IF [%DAY%]==[Mon] IF EXIST "%userprofile%\Lock_%YYYYMMDD%.lck" EXIT
IF [%DAY%]==[Mon] IF NOT EXIST "%userprofile%\Lock_%YYYYMMDD%.lck" ECHO Script has run %YYYYMMDD% already>>"%userprofile%\Lock_%YYYYMMDD%.lck"

<The rest of your batch logic below >
<Or you can CALL or START EXEs      >
<Scooby wanna scoobie snack         >
EXIT
```

---

### Scheduled Task Trigger

**Note:** You will schedule with this method for BOTH the above listed methods and scripts.

> **At log on**
>
> This trigger causes the task to run when a user logs on to the
>   computer, and the trigger's settings allow you to specify that the
>   task should be triggered when any user logs on the computer or when a
>   specific user logs on.
>
> <sub>[source](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748841(v=ws.11).aspx)</sub>

[image]

---

### Further Resources

- [IF](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)
- [Task Scheduler Triggers](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748841(v=ws.11).aspx)